# How can i create a method that will write the score to a file called score.csv in Java

Tags: java, opencsv

The method will take a param score which is a integer and will add it to the csv.
I am familiar with writing and reading csvs in python but this is my first time doing such thing in Java.
I want to write a method in such a way that whenever i call this it should add the score to the csv for later use.

```
writescoretocsv(score)
```

```
static void writescoretocsv(int score) {
    //What do i do here
  }
```

Comment: Use a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)). In `append` mode.

Comment: You *are* supposed to try. This is not a free programming service.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writescoretocsv(int score, File file) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
            writer.println(score);
        }
}
```

You get the file by entering the path name in the constructor: `new File("/example.csv")`